# how to properly use expression '3000 strong' army?

Tags: phrases, expressions

i recall reading some phrase to express when one wants to assess the size of a group or army:
"he has 3000-strong army", not in a sense "strong army" but to estimate the size of army.

"there is a group of 3000 strong" or "over a million strong"

how to use this phrase with "strong"  properly?

Comment: [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/strong) has an example: "an army ten thousand strong".

Comment: Found online as *a 1000-strong army* or *an army 1000 strong.* IDK if the positioning is relevant. Good luck.

Comment: Whether you hyphenate is a matter of style; consult any style guide you use, or search all the questions about hyphens on here.

Comment: Surely you would hyphenate if it's an adjectival phrase - _a 1000-strong army_ - but not otherwise - _the army was a thousand strong_?

Comment: The usual mantra is to hyphenate even remotely odd compound adjectives – I think this _has to be_ an adjective rather than say a quantifier/'numeralifier' – when used prenominally, but not usually when used predicatively. And 'a 3000 strong army' could just about be misconstrued at first glance, while 'an army 3000 strong' can't be.

Comment: So what is actually the question here? The cited "an army ten thousand strong" doesn't use *of*; "a 3000-strong army" is a standard compound adjective. I think the lack of prior research here is a problem because it doesn't tell us what you're actually looking for.